# XCode 6.3 Warning: synthesize property

Tags: xcode, dynamic, warnings

In new Xcode 6.3 I get this warning:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'homeInt'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

How I can remove it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I simply removed this property declaration, because it has already been declared in parent class

Answer (score 115):

If you are overriding the same property from the super class on purpose, then in your `*.m` or `*.mm` file, add `@dynamic` like:

```
@implementation MyClass

@dynamic homeInt;

// ...

@end
```

If not, rename the property.

Answer (score 10):

Following on @mplace's comment, in my case I was overriding the property to refine the type of the property to a subclass of the original class of the property. So, I did need the @property override.

Here's what I'm using:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-synthesis"
// superclass type for currentValue was "id"
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *currentValue;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Note that it's "-Wobjc-property-synthesis" and not "-Wno-objc-property-synthesis"

See also https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/660

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid adding `@dynamic <varName>` each place that you have overridden a super class's property *intentionally*, you can add the `-Wno-objc-property-synthesis` flag to "Other Warning Flags" under your projects build settings. This will suppress the warning project-wide.

Comment: This isn't suppressing the warnings for me... I'm using Cocoapods, not sure if that is overriding my flags.

Comment: -Wno-objc-property-synthesis does not work for me either to suppress this  warning. Any one else have ideas?

Comment: Let me refine that. It doesn't work when I put it inline with the code with "#pragma clang diagnostic ignored", but it does work when I put it with the compiler flags. I'd rather not make it general across all my code with the compiler flags...

Answer (score 3):

this cause by child class define the same property name override to parent class，such as：

1）child class "AFHTTPSessionManager" have define :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPResponseSerializer <AFURLResponseSerialization> * **responseSerializer**;
```

2）parent class "AFURLSessionManager" have define:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <AFURLResponseSerialization> **responseSerializer**;
```

3）cause by above, warning come! if want remove it ,just rename the conflict property name!

4) or as it suggest, add "@dynamic homeInt" in your implement file;

Comment: I see the same warnings for AFNetworking. Question is, are these anything to be concerned about? Do they even need attention for this library

Comment: it has fixed! https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/3fc8071582dfa552cb06b0dc7f1104c6bf5301f1  @BradThomas

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who accidentally ends sentences with a semicolon;

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to Xcode 6.3, simply update AFNetworking to version 2.5.2 and these warnings should disappear.

Comment: This is correct for warnings resulting from AFNetworking properties. The original question wasn't about one of those though.

Answer (score 0):

```
@synthesize homeInt = _ homeInt;
...

@end
```

Comment: @dynamic is better